# Unable to change default radius value using folium CircleMarker

Tags: python-3.6, folium

I am unable to change the default circle marker size in folium.

This is what my code looks like:

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("Volcanoes_USA.txt")
map = folium.Map(location=[46,-120],zoom_start=5)
fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")

def colorcode(x):
    if x in range(0,1600):
        color = 'green'
    elif x in range(1600,2200):
        color = 'orange'
    elif x in range(2200,2800):
        color = 'red'
    else:
        color = 'darkred'
    return color

lat = list(data["LAT"])
long = list(data["LON"])
elev = list(data["ELEV"])

for lt,ln,el in zip(lat,long,elev):
    fg.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location = [lt,ln],
                               radius = 10,
                               color = 'black',
                               fill_color = colorcode(int(el)),
                               fill_opacity = 0.6,
                               popup = "Elevation: %s meters" %el))

map.add_child(fg)
map.save("Volcanoes1.html")
```

And this is how my output looks no matter whatever radius value I use.
[image]

Can someone please help?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Updating the folium version to 0.5.0 fixed it. If you are using anaconda like I was, here's the command to update it:

```
conda update -c conda-forge folium
```